# wordpress media upload to rename files appropriately if file exists

Tags: wordpress, file, upload, media, rename

I'm creating a plugin in wordpress that uses the wp media uploader to upload files to the site. Problem is that if a file exists with the same name, the name of the file being currently uploaded is appended with a number at the end.

This is a problem if I upload file001.pdf and then the next file is renamed to file0012.pdf instead of file001-2.pdf
It's a problem because then the user may think that is file 12 and not version 2 of file 1.

How can i change that so if there's already a file in the system with the same name, the file being uploaded gets the right rename?

**EDIT**

So I found out there's a function in wp-includes/functions.php called *wp_unique_filename* which will check for unique file names and increment until the name is unique. I just need to find a way now to customize that function on the plugin directory.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides one hook ***wp_handle_upload_prefilter*** as below

```
function handle_uploadedimage($arr) {

        $random_number = md5(rand(10000,99999));
        $ext = pathinfo($arr['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $arr['name'] = $random_number .'.'.$ext;

        return $arr;
    }
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'handle_uploadedimage', 1, 1);
```